# Getting browser-style tabs in emacs

Tags: emacs

*Really* new programming student here, and I'm trying to get tabs in emacs (browser style, like Aquamacs has).

So, how do you get tabs in emacs?  A strip of labels showing me which buffers I have open, and clicking on one of them selects that buffer.

I have googled this extensively, but not being fluent in elisp makes it really hard to understand. I have installed the tabbar package, but I do not know where to go from here.

What do I want? Just tabs, and a command to open new tabs, for example C-t (or whatever is best).

Comment: Here is a link to the authoritative thread on the subject entitled "**Browser-style 'tabs' for emacs?**":  http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/10081/browser-style-tabs-for-emacs  There are multiple very good answers, and there are nearly 4,000 views and growing each day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have installed the tabbar package, but I do not know where to go from here.

The `tabbar` library provides a *global minor mode* named `tabbar-mode`, so you will want to enable that in your init file. If it's installed somewhere in your `load-path` then the following will work:

```el
(when (require 'tabbar nil t)
  (tabbar-mode 1))
```

There is lots of documentation in the library's Commentary, which you can visit like so:

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `find-library` <kbd>RET</kbd> `tabbar` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

[Try this](https://emacswiki.org/emacs/TabBarMode), it's called tabbar and should allow you to do what you're looking for.

Comment: The OP said that he has already installed tabbar. Please try to help with the actual question, which, with respect to tabbar, would provide some help for getting started using it.

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers, `tabbar` is what you're looking for.
You need to copy it to wherever you keep your emacs files (if you don't have such a place - make one, `tabbar` will not be the last add-on you'll use :) ), load the file and start the `tabbar-mode`.
In the below code, the emacs files dir is .emacs.files and it is in my home dir.

> (setq tabbar-file
>         (expand-file-name "tabbar.el"
>               (expand-file-name  ".emacs.files" "~")))
>   (load-file tabbar-file)
>   (tabbar-mode 1)
>   (define-key global-map "\M-[" 'tabbar-backward)
>   (define-key global-map "\M-]" 'tabbar-forward)

In the above code, I also added binding of scrolling through the tabs to Alt-[ and Alt-].
As to opening new tabs - every time you'll open a new file, it will be opened in a new tab, so don't worry...